# PyAutoGUI Image Confidence

Tags: python, pyautogui

I wonder if anyone has encountered this strange phoneoneon that I can't explain...

```
import pyautogui as pag

pag.locateOnScreen('save_icon.png', confidence = 0.9) #Works all the time and return x,y

pag.click('save_icon.png', confidence = 0.9)   #Sometimes work, sometimes does not!
```

So my workaround solution is ....

```
_ = pag.locateOnScreen('save_icon.png', confidence = 0.9) 

pag.click(pag.center(_))
```

Anyone has a better solution? I checked and I have opencv-python installed already, so not sure why it works sometimes but not others!

Answer (score 1):

```
l, t, w, h = py.locateOnScreen("k.png", confidence=0.9)
py.click(l, t)
```

**locateOnScreen** returns a 4-integer tuple: left, top, width, height

**py.click(l, t)** will click the top left pixel of the found image.

Answer (score 0):

You have used an image to locate your click location, right? So instead, you can open your image in paint, take your mouse where you want to click and get the co-ordinates from the bottom left corner of the paint screen. Then, after doing that, you can save those co-ordinates in a txt file and then use it in pyautogui's `click()` function like this:

```py
from pyautogui import *
click((co-ordinates examples) 12, 34)
```

OR

```py
from pyautogui import *
mouseDown(12, 34)
mouseUp(12, 34)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to use image to locate click instead of 'hard-coding' the coordinate.

Comment: Then Sorry, I can't tell you as I have never tried locating and clicking with pyautogui

Comment: That's ok. Thanks for looking into this.